# ERROR TypeError: _co.onClickMe is not a function at Object.eval [as handleEvent]

Tags: angular

Here is the code -

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent  {

    pageHeader = 'Employee Detail';

    onClickMe() : void {
        console.log('Button Clicked');
    }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>Hello {{pageHeader ? pageHeader : 'No Header'}}</h1>
<input [(ngModel)] = 'name' type="text" />
<br />
you entered : {{name}}
<br />
<button on-click='onClickMe()'>Click Me</button>
<br />
```

**Error I am getting in console -**

```
app.component.html:6 ERROR TypeError: _co.onClickMe is not a function
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (app.component.html:6)
app.component.html:6 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_
```

I am trying to use event handler using click event on button. Any Help ??

Comment: I think you just need to change `on-click` to `(click)`?

Answer (score 0):

Two Corrections:

1. change on-click to (click) .

   2.
   `<input type='text' [(ngModel)]= 'name' name='name' />`

as , according to what you did , the two way data binding won't work without adding the attribute of the variable you are changing. in your case , it is : name;